# PHP foreach - Creating multple searchs in the same page

Tags: php, foreach

Firstly, I am a total php newby.
Secondly, below is the php header plus corresponding recursive commands for 2 photo lightboxes that are in the same html page.

Without the lines

getRecords() as $Title_row){ ?>

The page shows shows the first picture that is held in the external db table in the lightbox correctly.

Yet when I add the line below to add all the other entries in each table

getRecords() as $Title_row){ ?>

the page goes white and the browser html return is empty.

As I do not really understand what I am doing, I am stuck. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

---

```
<?php
$Title_find = $Lowdenphotoweb->newFindCommand('MASTER_photo');
$Title_findCriterions = array('Order_web'=>'*',);
foreach($Title_findCriterions as $key=>$value) {
    $Title_find->AddFindCriterion($key,$value);
}

fmsSetPage($Title_find,'Title',50); 

$Title_find->addSortRule('Order_web',1,FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND); 

$Title_result = $Title_find->execute(); 

if(FileMaker::isError($Title_result)) fmsTrapError($Title_result,"error.php"); 

fmsSetLastPage($Title_result,'Title',50); 

$Title_row = current($Title_result->getRecords());

?>


<?php
$Title1_find = $Lowdenphotoweb->newFindCommand('MASTER_photo');
$Title1_findCriterions = array('Order_web'=>'*',);
foreach($Title1_findCriterions as $key=>$value) {
    $Title1_find->AddFindCriterion($key,$value);
}

fmsSetPage($Title1_find,'Title',50); 

$Title1_find->addSortRule('Order_web',1,FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND); 

$Title1_result = $Title1_find->execute(); 

if(FileMaker::isError($Title1_result)) fmsTrapError($Title1_result,"error.php"); 

fmsSetLastPage($Title1_result,'Title',50); 

$Title1_row = current($Title1_result->getRecords());

?>


<!DOCTYPE html> 

            <!-- Lightbox Gallery -->

            <?php foreach($Title_result->getRecords() as $Title_row){ ?>
                <div class="hide">
                       <a data-group="gallery-1" data-caption="<?php echo $Title_row->getField('Title'); ?>" href="<?php echo $Title_row->getField('Pic_location'); ?>"></a>
                </div>

<?php foreach($Title2_result->getRecords() as $Title2_row){ ?>
                <div class="hide">
                       <a data-group="gallery-2" data-caption="<?php echo $Title2_row->getField('Title'); ?>" href="<?php echo $Title2_row->getField('Pic_location'); ?>"></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Lightbox Gallery End-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed out the closing brackets :

```
<?php foreach($Title_result->getRecords() as $Title_row){ ?>
                <div class="hide">
                       <a data-group="gallery-1" data-caption="<?php echo $Title_row->getField('Title'); ?>" href="<?php echo $Title_row->getField('Pic_location'); ?>"></a>
                </div>
<?php }?>

<?php foreach($Title2_result->getRecords() as $Title2_row){ ?>
                <div class="hide">
                       <a data-group="gallery-2" data-caption="<?php echo $Title2_row->getField('Title'); ?>" href="<?php echo $Title2_row->getField('Pic_location'); ?>"></a>
                </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: How depressing ... Worst thing is that they were there at the beginning.  It all works great. Can you suggest of a good place to start understanding php. There so many resources but most are rather obscure. Thanks you so much